# Getting started (again) with DevForce

Tags: windows-store, devforce

Getting started again after some years of inactivity.
Is there a sample, or documentation to get started with DevForce 2012 Windows Store Apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DevForce Resource Center](http://drc.ideablade.com) has all available resources for DevForce 2012.  There is a simple "app tour" sample available [here](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-windows-store-tour).